# need to create a webpack identity-loader

Tags: webpack

I would like to create a identity webpack loader, a loader that returns **the same** module object than without the loader :

```
require('identity!foo') === require('foo')
```

**first setback :**

```
module.exports = function(...args) {

    this.callback(null, ...args);
}
```

**second setback :**

```
const { stringifyRequest, getRemainingRequest } = require('loader-utils');
module.exports = function(source, map, meta) {

    const remainingRequest = stringifyRequest(this, getRemainingRequest(this));
    return `module.exports = require(${ remainingRequest });`;
}
```

(BTW, I don't understand why this attempt do not work)

Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the content that you got to the next loader.

```js
module.exports = function(content) {

    return content
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not satisfy `require('identity!foo') === require('foo')`

Comment: Why do you need to satisfy that?

Comment: If `foo` is a singleton, having `require('identity!foo') !== require('foo')` mean that `foo` is not a singleton.